# Error that the stack was damaged while using strcat_s

Tags: c, stack, strcat-s

I was studying `strcat_s` and I wrote the following code to practice it.

```
int main(void)
{
    char szPath[128] = { "C:\\Program Files\\" };

    strcat_s(szPath + strlen("C:\\Program Files\\"), sizeof(szPath), "CHS\\");
    strcat_s(szPath + strlen("C:\\Program Files\\CHS\\"), sizeof(szPath), "C programming");
    puts(szPath);
    return 0;
}
```

The output worked properly like 
`C:\Program Files\CHS\C programming`

but a debug error window popped up,

`Stack around the variable 'szPath' was corrupted.`
What is the cause?

Comment: please choose a language, either c or c++ but not both

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you send `szPath + strlen("C:\\Program Files\\")` as a parameter, then the size of the string is `sizeof(szPath) - strlen("C:\\Program Files\\")`.

Same for the second line - size is `sizeof(szPath) - strlen("C:\\Program Files\\CHS\\")`.

The string size is 128, but you send a pointer to the middle, where the number of available characters is smaller.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the debug version of `strcat_s` in visual studio deliberately overwrites the full  length of the buffer:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/strcat-s-wcscat-s-mbscat-s?view=vs-2019

> The debug library versions of these functions first fill the buffer with 0xFE. To disable this behavior, use _CrtSetDebugFillThreshold.

This means that if you give a size value that is too large the debug runtime should detect this by corrupting the stack.

In your case you aren't passing a pointer to the beginning of the buffer so your size is `strlen` bytes more than the available space. The simplest solution to to just pass the pointer unmodified to `strcat_s`, it does the `strlen` internally to find the current end of the string:

```
int main(void)
{
    char szPath[128] = { "C:\\Program Files\\" };

    strcat_s(szPath, sizeof(szPath), "CHS\\");
    strcat_s(szPath, sizeof(szPath), "C programming");
    puts(szPath);
    return 0;
}
```